# Is this assertion true or false? $(\exists x)(\exists y)(\forall z)(y \ne x+z \Rightarrow y\lt x)$ Cohn - Classic Algebra P7

Tags: logic, arithmetic, predicate-logic

$x,y,z\in\mathbb{N}$ with $0$

$(\forall x)(\forall y)(\exists z)(y \geq x \Rightarrow y=x+z)$

Can you help me with trivial thing above? I imagine it is because I am tired, but I can't see if this is true or false.

I always negate things to test if they are true or false, and $(\exists x)(\exists y)(\forall z)(y \ne x+z \Rightarrow y\lt x)$ seemed true, but so did the original statement

From, Clasic Algebra - Cohn.

Comment: You negated it incorrectly.

Comment: To clarify, the negation of implication is not given by reversing the implication sign. Instead it is $y \ge x \text{ AND } y \neq x+z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick any $x, y \in \mathbb N_0$ such that $y \geq x$. Then, let $z= y-x$  so that $y = x+z$. Hence, for every pair of natural numbers $(x, y)$ such that $y \geq x$, there does indeed exist a natural $z$ (namely, $z = y-x$, which depends on $x, y$) for which $y = x + z$. Hence, the posted statement is indeed true.

Your negation of the posted statement is incorrect. It should be $$\begin{align} \exists x \exists y \forall z\Big(\lnot(y\geq x \rightarrow  y = x+z)\Big) &\equiv \exists x \exists y \forall z \Big(\lnot(y \lt x \lor y = x+z)\Big)\\ \\ 
&\equiv \exists x \exists y \forall z \Big( y\geq x \land y \neq x+z\Big)
\end{align}$$

Comment: So both of my statements above were correct though weren't they, hence the confusion. Thank you for the correct negation, it has been a long time since I have done this stuff, but I am doing 'Classic Algebra' by Cohn, and it is where we start.

Comment: When I said correct, I meant true. Meaning: Was $(\exists x)(\exists y)(\forall z)(y \ne x+z \Rightarrow y\lt x)$ true aswell?

Comment: And what I meant by incorrect is that your negation of the original assertion is not its negation. The original assertion is true. The negation of the original assertion, as I've posted it, is false.

Comment: Sorry I am not being clear. I knew(in the first comment) that my negation was wrong, but was my incorrect negation true?

Original statement was true, negation was untrue, incorrect negation is T or F?

and my "when I said correct, I meant true$\dots$" was only a correction to my first comment, not my original question.

Comment: Got it. The incorrect negation is true.